# .htaccess rewrite to prettify and redirect the old url without causing an infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Here's what I am trying to achieve

Prettify the old url -

- from: `example.com/dir-1/dir-2/my-file.html`
- to  :   `example.com/my-file.html`

And every time someone tries to visit `example.com/dir-1/dir-2/my-file.html`, redirect to `example.com/my-file.html`.

This is what I have so far in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^my-file.html /dir-1/dir-2/my-file.html 
Redirect 301 /dir-1/dir-2/my-file.html /my-file.html
```

Adding Redirect 301 give an error in the browser "redirected you too many times.". Is there a way to do this without causing an infinite loop of redirects?

Comment: are you redirecting to new website?

Comment: Nope, same website.

Comment: one more thing you want to rewrite or redirect means if some user visits `example.com/my-file.html` it will access `example.com/dir-1/dir-2/my-file.html` in server.

Comment: Location of the original html file is **example.com/dir-1/dir-2/my-file.html**.  

However, regardless of what the user types (ugly or the prettified url) the link in the browser should appear as the short version : **example.com/my-file.html**.